# Can i get config class name that initialized my bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have config class and spring component

```
package packageA;

@Component
public class A {
}



package packageConfig;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("packageA")
public class ConfigClass {
}
```

Also a have another component that autowires my component `A`

```
@Component
public class B {

    @Autowired
    private A a;
}
```

So my question is "Is that possible to get to know the config class name that scanned my autowired bean (though the debug in post construct or smthg like that). I dont need this name in code actualy. I just need to know the config class name"

Comment: what is the use case? why do you want this information?

Comment: @pvpkiran i have a very huge project with a huge amount of configurations. and i just don't know which config initialized an autowired component

Comment: It's an interesting question from a technical standpoint, but sounds like a dark path to down in terms of architecture/development practice.  You care about the config not where it comes from.  If you need metadata, put it into the config.